# Mounting sdb as a secondary storage drive

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I have just finished a build with an Asus M4A88T-M, and an AMD Athlon 250 3.0gig cpu. The graphics are AMD and are in the board. Because of the great cost of new HDs, I used an older Maxtor 160 IDE as the boot (it had never been a boot drive) and a {I think!} WD 100 gig IDE as a storage drive. Both have been formatted in ext. 4. The system is completely Ubuntu 11.10 and very likely to remain same.

Years ago, when I wanted to gain access to the second (sdb) hd for storage, all I had to do was go into the GUI interface (on Gnome ... I know not what version ... ), identify myself as the root and then change permissions on the HD.

How do I get the system to recognize the secondary HD as a storage vessel and not as a boot disk? I don't remember seeing any questions regarding this issue as the OS was being installed on SDA. Help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to mount it? The fact that it might be bootable does not change anything. Btw. sdb is the whole drive, please do not mount the drive (sdb), mount the partition instead (sdb1)

As superuser edit your /etc/fstab and add a second list of this kind:

```
UUID=072aa6ac-20a8-4c76-84c2-d68173d98744 /foomountpoint ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Replace foomountpoint by your mountpoint. This folder should exist and be empty!

The UUID you can find when invoking:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid

mkr@mkrubuntu:~$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid/
insgesamt 1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 2012-01-16 07:53 072aa6ac-20a8-4c76-84c2-d68173d98744 -> ../../sda6
```